# href inside href

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a clickable panel within which I have a tooltip. The code looks as follows:

```
<a href="/venues/manage/">
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <img src="/img/venue.svg">
     <h5 class="text-vert crop"><b>Venue Title</b><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Verified Venue">Verified</a></h5>
    </div>
 </div>
</a>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
</script>
```

When I hover over the tooltip text it works fine. Something about the tooltips messes with the main link `<a href="/venues/manage/">`. When I click the image, the link works fine. When I click the text `Venue Title` it works fine. But if I click anywhere else in the `<div class="col-md-4">` (such as to the right of the text) the link doesn't work.

Is it possible to have a `<a>` tooltip within another `<a>`?

Comment: No. You cannot have nested `<a>`s and nested `<p>`s.

Comment: you're wrong @MuhammadUsman, please wait... my answer

Comment: Don't be sure of yourself.... One minut...., please take a look, wrap your second 'a' inside a object tag.

Comment: @pbenard yes, I've seen one possibility today... I've never used `object` before.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to have nested a please do the following changes ....

You have to wrap the nested a inside a `object` tag.

```
<a href="/venues/manage/">
 <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
     <img src="/img/venue.svg">
     <h5 class="text-vert crop">
         <b>Venue Title</b>
         <object><a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Verified Venue">Verified</a></object>
     </h5>
    </div>
 </div>
</a>
```

Here is a bootply (see the generated HTML) : http://www.bootply.com/MmYwCLTF0P

Here is a conference from Vitaly Friedman : https://vimeo.com/162334949

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: Nested `<a>` elements are invalid HTML

Comment: @j08691 I'm agree with you. It's a bad hack... But it does the job....

Comment: What is this magic.