# Laravel Blade - My div inside a tag have unpredictable render on browser

Tags: html, css

Heei, I have a problem when view my html result with blade laravel. Look at this pictures

**Code**
[image]

**HTML**

```
<section class="list_events">
  @foreach($acara as $value)
    <div class="col s12 m6">
      <a class="test" style="display: inline-block">
        <figure class="card">
          <img src="some_photo_from_db" alt="" />
          <figcaption>
            <p>{{ $value->tanggal_event }}</p>
            <p>{{ $value->nama_event }}</p>
            <div>
              <a href="#">{{ $value->lokasi_event }}</a>
              <a href="#">{{ $value->kategori_event }}</a>
            </div>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
  @endforeach
</section>
```

CSS

```
   * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style-type: none;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    a {
      color: inherit;
    }
    /*and some other css which is not appropriate with this case*/

body {
  font-size: 16px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
main {
  padding: 20px 0;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**Result**
[image]

Please look. Why the `a` tag not wrapping the `figure`? and the `a`tag looks like repeat on every element inside `figure`?

Comment: I think it's because your <img> is not closed properly. You have to add a "/" at the end. Like this: <img src="something.jpeg"/>. by the way: Please never post pictures of code

Comment: In HTML, you don't need end tag. It's in XHTML.

Comment: I've try it. But still same result. When I change the `a` into div it have normal result

Comment: Please paste your code as text.

Comment: Done @NicolasCami :). Look at my update question

Comment: Well, we would need a complete snippet with both HTML and CSS to check what's going on.

Comment: Ok, wait the minute @NicolasCami

Comment: I already check the css, and I don't have any 'weird' css. I just have reset css and styling for the box shadow figure @NicolasCami

Comment: Could it be caused because you are wrapping 2 ``<a href``'s inside a ``<a href``? Don't know how html responds to that?

Comment: I want to make the hyperlink on `figure`. So I wrap the `figure` inside `a`. How can I make `figure` become hyperlink without wrapping it inside `a` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to these ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41959446/href-inside-href), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882916/are-you-allowed-to-nest-a-link-inside-of-a-link)) answers. Nesting an `<a href>` is bad practice. You can force to make it work by wrapping the nested href's inside an `<object>` tag

Comment: wooow, it's work!! Even if it 'not valid' but it still work

Answer (score 0):

You have child links inside parent link, instead of this you can just move a link tag from your wrapper to the image (or any another element inside `figure`).

```
<figure class="card">
  <a href="#"><img src="some_photo_from_db" alt="" /></a>
  <figcaption>
    <p>{{ $value->tanggal_event }}</p>
    <p>{{ $value->nama_event }}</p>
    <div>
      <a href="#">{{ $value->lokasi_event }}</a>
      <a href="#">{{ $value->kategori_event }}</a>
    </div>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```